# How does a process sleep on an event in System V?

Tags: process, sleep

I came across that, in Unix System V, the events are mapped to an address in the kernel space, and that processes sleep on such an event, and an interrupt wakes up a process using this address.

But how does this work? How is it implemented?

I'm still not getting what they mean by, an *"event is mapped to an address"*. Sorry if the question is naive.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory):

> POSIX provides a standardized API for using shared memory (*POSIX
>   Shared Memory*). This uses the function `shm_open` from `sys/mman.h`.
>   POSIX interprocess communication (part of the POSIX:XSI Extension)
>   includes the shared-memory functions `shmat`, `shmctl`, `shmdt` and
>   `shmget`. **UNIX System V provides an API for shared memory as well**.
>   This uses `shmget` from `sys/shm.h`. BSD systems provide "anonymous mapped
>   memory" which can be used by several processes.
>
> The shared memory created by `shm_`open is persistent. It stays in the
>   system until explicitly removed by a process. This has a drawback that
>   if the process crashes and fails to clean up shared memory it will
>   stay until system shutdown. To avoid this issue `mmap` can be used to
>   create a shared memory. Two communicating processes should open a
>   temporary file with the same name and do `mmap`on it to get a file
>   mapping in the memory. As a result changes in mapped memory are
>   visible by both processes at the same time. The advantage of these
>   approaches is that when both processes exit, OS will automatically
>   close the files and remove shared memory.

At times, processes want to wait until a certain event occurs, such as a device to initialize, I/O to complete or a timer to expire. In such a case, the process is said to sleep on that event. The problem of enabling a "sleeping" process on a shared-memory multiprocessor is a difficult one, especially if the process is to be awakened by an interrupt-time event.